# Accessing cakephp session variable from a php script?

Tags: cakephp

How can you access the cakephp session variable from a php script?

I tried `$_SESSION` but it returns empty. I specifically want to get to the Auth session information.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try this...

session_name('CAKEPHP'); 
session_start(); 
print_r($_SESSION);

Comment: Ah yes, exactly what I needed too! Cheers.