# sharing session across folder

Tags: php, session, cakephp

I am having issues sharing a session between folders in CakePHP and found a solution here: [Access cakephp session (auth) from outside cakephp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619877/access-cakephp-session-auth-from-outside-cakephp)

It gives me an empty session outside the cakephp folder

```
<?php
session_name('CAKEPHP');
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);

?>
```

Thanking you.

Comment: seems all right, try deleting the cache

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the name of the session with `session_name('CAKEPHP')` This may not be what cake is using. Try removing that line and PHP will use the default `session_name('PHPSESSID')`.

**Edit**
You may want to check out [Using Cake sessions outside of Cake](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/brightball/2009/02/18/using-cake-sessions-outside-of-cake)

Comment: its not working at all, cakephp wont let me sign in . Configure::write('Session.cookie', 'CAKEPHP'); is there in config file

Comment: i tried your link..it starts a new session outside the folder

Answer (score 0):

What are you naming the session? $_SESSION['CAKEPHP'] also will return empty when placed inside a CakePHP app as well. The best way to make sure you can read it is to know what you want to read and then name it correctly in the CakePHP app you are writing.

$this->Session->write('Name.item1', 'value1');
$this->Session->write('Name.item2', 'value2');
$this->Session->write('Name.item3', 'value3');
...

Then you can access this via:

```
$_SESSION['Name']
```

and it will return

```
array (
  'item1' => 'value1',
  'item2' => 'value2',
  'item3' => 'value3',
)
```

In cake you can access it like:

```
$this->Session->read('Name.item1')
```

and it will return

```
value1
```

So simply calling `$_SESSION['CAKEPHP']` will not work, unless you are writing to `CAKEPHP`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using php sessions? If you are using DB sessions you can just do a mysql query for the session and put it in $_SESSION

Comment: i can get it from the db, but how do i put it in the session?

Comment: and how would i authenticate a user using the db?

Answer (score 0):

In the process of migrating a large app from CakePHP to Yii controller by controller we came across the same need, I believe all you're missing is setting the correct session.save_path which ( at least in my case ) wasn't just /tmp/, but instead %CAKE_PATH%/tmp/sessions/.

```
ini_set('session.save_path', TMP . 'sessions');
```

that line and all the other cakephp session config setup can be found in cake/libs/cake_session.php ( for 1.3.10 at least ). From there setting the same name and doing a session_start() should be sufficient.

Cheers,
shean

Answer (score 0):

I recognise your symptoms. This is a particularly nasty problem that took me a lot of tracking down when I experienced this, but I nailed it in the end and am delighted to share what I feel confident will be the answer with someone else.

Suhosin's suhosin.session.cryptdocroot option was the entire cause of the problem. Check your webserver with phpinfo.php and look to see if Suhosin is enabled. Suhosin creates session variables in DocRoot according to the subdomain name. With two or more subdomains the session variables can't see each other and the value of each other precisely because they are stored in separate sub-folders. Insane, yes. However there is a simple enough fix for this, as follows.

Simply add these two lines to your php.ini file.

```
suhosin.session.cryptdocroot=Off
suhosin.cookie.cryptdocroot=Off
```

and voila! Session variables across domains are now working as they should.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly please check your Sessions are working fine from `phpinfo()`

if its all fine try

```
session_set_cookie_params(0);//before session_start function
session_start();
```

Also Change session on your server to see exactly what is creating Issue.

If you are on a shared hosting then you can create separate php.ini for setting values of

```
[PHP]
session.cookie_domain = ".domain.com";
session.save_path = "/home/users/web/foldr1/domain.com/sessions/";
```

Hope this way it will be easy for you to find the root cause.

Answer (score -1):

**Check this it may help you**

//to share between folders use session save_path

```
session_save_path('/home/www/sessions');
session_start();
$_SESSION["CAKE_PHP"] = "my_name";
```