# Unique session for cakephp app and pages

Tags: php, session, cakephp

I want to use sessions between some php pages, and my cakephp app.
However, my cakephp app doesn't seem to blend with my pages, and it creates another session instead, leaving me with two sessions opened at the same time:
one for my cakephp app, and one for my other pages.

How can I use the same session for both my app and pages that are outside of the app?

I'm using cakephp version 2.3.0

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619877/access-cakephp-session-auth-from-outside-cakephp , this may help you provided the domain for cakephp app and corephp pages is same.

Comment: @HarishLalwani thanks, they are on the same domain, however, I have this the other way around : a session starts in my corephp files, and I want to continue it through cakephp

Comment: Please always mention your _exact_ CakePHP version (last line in `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt` or `lib/Cake/VERSION.txt`) - thanks!

Comment: @ndm it says 2.3.0