# how to access CakePHP session from another PHP script?

Tags: php, session, cakephp

I am trying to implement a "Single Sign On (SSO)" between my CakePHP script and my wordpress blog. I researched online for it and found some questions such as
[Access cakephp session (auth) from outside cakephp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619877/access-cakephp-session-auth-from-outside-cakephp)
and 
[Accessing cakephp session variable from a php script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988156/accessing-cakephp-session-variable-from-a-php-script)

To do a quick test I then created a test php file in my webroot directory of my CakePHP with below code

```
<?php
 session_name('NMCORE');
 session_start();
 print_r($_SESSION);
?>
```

*NMCORE* is my session name. It's not the default CAKEPHP. I also confirmed it by putting `debug(session_name());` in my controller. But the above code returns a blank array. I'm not sure why it's not working. I need your help to figure it out.

The configuration for my Session in my CakePHP's core.php file is

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'cake',
    'cookie' => 'NMCORE',
    'timeout' => 43200, //30 days
    'autoRegenerate' => true,
    'checkAgent' => true
));
```

Does anybody have an idea on why this is not working?

Answer (score 1):

I figured that out. I'm using `'defaults' => 'cake'` in my

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'cake',
    'cookie' => 'NMCORE',
    'timeout' => 43200, //30 days
    'autoRegenerate' => true,
    'checkAgent' => true
));
```

When I changed it to 'php' then it worked.

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'php',
    'cookie' => 'NMCORE',
    'timeout' => 43200, //30 days
    'autoRegenerate' => true,
    'checkAgent' => true
));
```